# Pygame beginner programs, screen undefined

Tags: python, pygame

```
AMOUNT = 1
x = 175
y = 175

def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
    screen.fill( (251,251,251) )
    BoxAmountCalc(humaninput)
    DrawBoxCalc()
    pygame.display.flip()

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                return

def BoxAmountCalc(x):
    x = (2**humaninput) * (2**humaninput)
    size = 600/x
    return size
def DrawBoxCalc():
    while True:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0), (x,y,size,size))
        AMOUNT += 1
        x = x + size
        x = y + size
        pygame.display.flip()
        if AMOUNT > humaninput:
            break
```

I've left out a few parts of the code, some of the variable definitions, but when I try to run this code it gives me an error saying that "screen" is not defined.

Is this because I need it to be defined as a parameter for the function and then pass it into the function, or am I missing something completely here?

Thank you for looking, I'm sorry for a very beginner question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because I need it to be defined as a parameter for the
>   function and then pass it into the function.

Yes.  Once a function finishes executing, the variables created therein are destroyed.  Here is an example:

```
def go():
    x = 10

go()
print(x)

--output:--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Same thing here:

```
def go():
    x = 10


def stay():
    print(x) 

go()
stay()

--output:--
 File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
    stay()
  File "1.py", line 6, in stay
    print(x) 
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

But:

```
x = 10

def go():
    print(x)

go()

--output:--
10
```

And better:

```
def go(z):
    print(z)

x = 10
go(x)

--output:--
10
```

Try to keep your functions self contained, which means they should accept some input and produce some output without using variables outside the function.

In your code, you can do:

`DrawBoxCalc(screen)` and `def DrawBoxCalc(screen)`:

but you also have an issue with humaninput.  I would try to define DrawBoxCalc as DrawBoxCalc(humaninput, screen), and call it with both args.  That means you will have to define main as main(humaninput).

Also, function names should start with a lower case letter, and python uses what is called snake_case for lower case names, so `draw_box_calc`, and class names should start with a capital letter and they can use camel case: `class MyBox`.

Comment: This just saved me about 3 more questions I was going to ask, thank you for the help.